# comparing two series object of different length

Tags: python, pandas

i want to create a new column in df, built on compare of two series objects, when i am trying to compare this two series  i am getting

`ValueError: can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

i am trying:

```
df = ((data1['price'] >= data2['amount_min']) & (data1['price'] <= data2['amount_max']))
```

example of series objects:

```
data1 = 0 102340          
        1 234244 
        etc
data2 has only one value, let it be 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df2['a'][0]` as scalar value instead of Pandas Series:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1, 2, 3]),
                   columns=['a'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1]),
                   columns=['a'])

df1['a'] > df2['a'][0]

# output
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

type(df2['a'])   # pandas.core.series.Series
type(df2['a'][0])  # numpy.int32
```